# Using AngularJS component props

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to angularJS, and now I'm trying to realize some parts.

The questions is: how do I get access to callback onFinish() which is passed to component "my-timer" and run it?  this.onFinish() returns the error.

Here is my markup:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl as myCtrl">
  <div>
    Status: {{myCtrl.status ? myCtrl.status : 'Waiting...'}}
  </div>

  <div>
    <button ng-click="myCtrl.addTimer(5)">Add timer</button>
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="timer in myCtrl.timers">
    <div>
      <h3>Timer {{timer.id}}</h3>
      <button ng-click="myCtrl.removeTimer($index)">X</button>
      <my-timer id="{{timer.id}}" start-seconds="{{timer.seconds}}" on-finish="myCtrl.onFinish(endTime)"></my-timer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is index.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', class {
      constructor($scope) {
        this.status = null;
        this.timerId = 0;
        this.timers = [];
        this.addTimer(10);
        this.addTimer(3);
      console.log($scope);
      }

  addTimer(seconds) {
    this.timers.push({
      id: this.timerId++,
      seconds
    });
  }

  removeTimer(index) {
    this.timers.splice(index, 1);
  }

onFinish(endTime){
    this.status = `Timer finished at ${endTime}`;
  console.log(endTime);
}

});

app.component('myTimer', {
  bindings: {
    id: '@',
    startSeconds: '@',
    onFinish: '&',
  },

  controller: function($interval, $scope) {
    this.endTime = null;

this.$onInit = function() {
  this.countDown();
};

this.countDown = function() {
  $interval(() => {
    this.startSeconds = ((this.startSeconds - 0.1) > 0) ? (this.startSeconds - 0.1).toFixed(2) : 0;
  }, 100);
}; 
  },
template: `<span>{{$ctrl.startSeconds}}</span>`,
});
```

And here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulkotov/bp67uzy1/133/)

Comment: You can't access the function at all? Or it errors out after calling it?

Comment: When i use this.onFinish(...) in component's controller, Chrome's console says me "this.onFinish" is not a function. I believe that everything i declare inside controller,  goes to this: controller: { this.seconds = null; this.start = function()...} But have no access to function onFinish in 'bindings' section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.$onInit = function() {
  this.countDown();
};

this.onFinish('1');
```

The problem here is that you tried to execute `this.onFinish` right in controller's body. And that wont work that way. If you want this function to be called during initialization, move it to `$onInit`

```
this.$onInit = function() {
  this.countDown();
  this.onFinish('1');
 };
```

Otherwise, call it from another component method. You can only declare variables and component methods in controller body, but not call functions.

Comment: I've tried it but got: "TypeError: this.onFinish is not a function
    at controller ((index):76)..."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That helped me!